# add previous value to current value within in same group

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like below

```
id depid sal
1   1    100
2   1    200
3   2    300
4   2    400
```

I want my output to be like below given table.
In output whats happening is that, Sal value is increasing by adding a previous value of same deptid.

```
id depid sal
1   1    100
2   1    300
3   2    300
4   2    700
```

Any Idea how can I achieve this...? I'm using oracle database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analytic function.

```
select id, depid, sum(sal) over( partition by depid order by id) sal from test;
```

sum function in analytic way summing all row from beginning to current row and it is default behaviour

Extende version.

```
select id, depid, sum(sal) over( partition by depid order by id range unbounded preceding) sal from test;
```

And last options.

```
select id, depid, sum(sal) over( partition by depid order by id range between unbounded preceding and current row) sal from test;
```

Each of these examples do exactly the same. I've added it to show you how it's works.

For more information check documentation [Analitic function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24693_01/server.11203/e17118/functions004.htm)

*Added after comment.

```
select id, depid, sum(sal) over( partition by depid order by id rows 1 preceding) sal from test;

select id, depid, sum(sal) over( partition by depid order by id rows between 1 preceding and current row) sal from test;
```

Comment: First query is giving sum of all salary within a deptid, but if you see the expected output where sal getting added with last sal within same deptid ..!! Secondly your 2nd and 3rd query is not working...! I'm sorry 

Comment: All query should works. I've tested it on Oracle 11.2. I added two more example to sum sal from current row and one row before.